# Angular - Watching a form whether its $dirty - performance

Tags: angularjs

In my Angular app, I'm setting the placeholders in my form through some code in the controller (showing particular text for particular times of day).

When a user begins typing into any field of that form, I want all placeholders to be cleared.

To do this I understand I need to use `$dirty` using `$watch`

```
$scope.$watch('myForm.$dirty', function() {
    //clear the placeholders
}, true);
```

My question is `watch` quite performance intensive in this situation or is there a more optimised way?

Thanks.

Comment: why u trying to set placeholder from controller instead you can set it directly to control on form?

Comment: So if I already bind some text in: `<input name="in1" type="text" placeholder="{{in1Placeholder}}"/>` would i then use a `ng-if`? Is is this better performance wise?

Comment: why you are trying to bind placeholder dynamically?

Comment: As mentioned above in my question - showing particular text for particular times of day

Comment: @usrMod2 watch might solve your problem but you need to set watch for each controller where you want this functionality

Answer (score 0):

If you use $dirty and $watch it will work but it will clear all placeholders before you begins type or on controller load.
    So, you can try this its work for me.

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
<input type="text" ng-model="name1" ng-change="change()" placeholder={{placeholder1}}>
  <input type="text" ng-model="name2" ng-change="change()" placeholder={{placeholder2}}>
  <input type="text" ng-model="name3" ng-change="change()" placeholder={{placeholder3}}>
</div>

function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.placeholder1="name";
  $scope.placeholder2="city";
  $scope.placeholder3="address";

  $scope.change=function() {
    $scope.placeholder1="";
    $scope.placeholder2="";
    $scope.placeholder3="";
  };
}
```